# Bullet points on li element not displaying on page

Tags: html, css

In the below code unordered list bullet symbols are not displaying. Can any one help me.

expected output:

- Smart class (Digital Technology) as a part of classroom teaching.

**html**

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- main content -->
    <section class="col-sm-8 maincontent">
      <h3>Our Facilities</h3>

      <img src="assets/images/about.jpg" alt="" class="img-rounded pull-right" width="300" />
      <ul>
        <li>Smart class (Digital Technology) as a part of classroom teaching.</li>
        <li>Karate Classes</li>
        <li>Well equipped, Compute Lab and Science Lab.</li>
        <li>CET classes,</li>
        <li>Sports Academy.</li>
        <li>Eco and Environment Club,Adventure Club.</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Likely suppressed by your CSS - look for `list-style-type: none;`

Comment: Or the short hand/lazy  version, `list-style:none`

Comment: it's not showing bullets

Comment: without css we can not under the problem, please post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: inspect your element whether any parent element having list-style:none

Answer (score -1):

Check your CSS. Make sure it contains something similar to `ul {list-style-type: circle;}`.
For other style types, see the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp).

Comment: Or does NOT contain a list-style entry